# Django - get all related models related to each object

Tags: python, django

Basically, I do have few models that refer to each other.
I hope I relations between those alright, but I'm not 100% sure.
**models.py**

```
class Table(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField(unique = True)
    isFree = models.BooleanField(default = True)

class MenuItem(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    quantityInStock = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=10)

class Order(models.Model):
    tableFK = models.ForeignKey(Table, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    opened_at = models.DateTimeField('date_created', default = timezone.now)
    closed_at = models.DateTimeField('date_closed', blank = True, null = True)
    paid = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    class Meta:
         ordering = ('-opened_at',)

class OrderDetails(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('CHOICE1', 'choice1'),
        ('CHOICE2', 'choice2'),
        ('CHOICE3', 'choice3'),
        ('CHOICE4', 'choice4'),
        ('CHOICE5', 'choice5')
    )

    orderFK = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    menuitemFK = models.ForeignKey(MenuItem, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default = 1)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices= STATUS_CHOICES, default='choice1')
```

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    orders = Order.objects.select_related("tableFK").filter(paid=False)

    template = loader.get_template('autowaiter/index.html')
    context = {
        'orders':orders
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

What I'm achieving now, is that I do have Orders objects. But in index.html I would like to display something like:

- Table
- "earliest" order to table
- ALL orderDetails elements grouped to each orderFK

Could you please point me out example and theory which I'm lacking to proceed?

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup

Comment: you can use django template tag filter and show all value in template related table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I have understood what you're looking for, a very simple template based on your current model structure could look something like this:

```
{% for table in tables %}
    <h3>Table {{ table.number }}</h3>
    <p>Order opened at {{ table.orders.earliest.opened_at }}</p>
    {% for orderdetail in table.orders.earliest.orderdetails.all %}
        Status: {{ orderdetail.status }}, Quantity: {{ orderdetail.quantity }}
        </br>
    {% endfor %}
    <hr/>
{% endfor %}
```

But you'd need to make some tweaks to your models to support that, namely adding a `related_name` attribute to your foreign key field in `Order`:

```
tableFK = models.ForeignKey(Table, related_name='orders', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and in `OrderDetail`:

```
orderFK = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='orderdetails', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

as well as adding a `get_latest_by` attribute to the `Meta` class in `Order`:

```
class Meta:
    ordering = ('-opened_at',)
    get_latest_by = 'opened_at'
```

(that supports the use of [`earliest`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#earliest)).

Lastly, the query in your view would need to query the top level `Table` objects that have unpaid orders, rather than querying orders themselves:

```
def index(request):
    # Query the tables with unpaid orders
    tables = Table.objects.filter(orders__paid=False)

    template = loader.get_template('autowaiter/index.html')
    context = {
        'tables': tables
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

Comment: I think this is what I needed, with
tables = Table.objects.filter(orders__paid=False) most.
I couldn't find syntax that would fit my needs.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't, Try [django_tables2](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), HTML table(s) can be generated and rendered with columns hyper linking as per foreign keys to new page or table.

Comment: This is definitely something I would try! Thanks a lot!